# How to show "Product not found" if Id did not match with the any of the data base id In react?

Tags: reactjs, database, api, jsx, json-server

Here I have used a local JSON server to fetch the data. I am using useParams for an id and passing the id into the URL. When the users enter an id in the URL that is not matched with any of the database's id, it should give the error by saying product not found.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function ProductDetails() {
  const params = useParams();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
// here I am fetching the data through local json ser

Heading
=======

ver
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/product/${params.Product_id}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          setData(res);
          console.log(res);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      setLoading(false);
      setError(true);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "blue" }} to="/Product">
        Go Back
      </Link>

      {data ? (
        <h1>
          {data.name}
          <br />
          {data.price}
        </h1>
      ) : (
        <p>Product not found</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductDetails;
```

Comment: From what I understood, you want to display product not found, if the array of products is empty. But your implementation is wrong, first you are setting a state as an empty array, then change it to some object with name and price. 
Do you know exactly which kind of data are you expecting from your BE?

Comment: You understood right. I am expecting an array of object type data.

Comment: then, you should check, like data.length > 0 ? logic :  null